# Поиск по SQLite через EditText

Tags: java, android, sqlite, search

Вопрос наверное слишком общий, но на конкретном примере моего кода может подскажите кто. У меня есть `DialogFragment`:

```
final ListView mListHeads = headsView.findViewById(R.id.list_heads);
final EditText mSearchHead = headsView.findViewById(R.id.search_head);
final ViewPager mViewPager = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.container);

    // Открываем базу данных
    DBAssetHelper dbSetup = new DBAssetHelper(getActivity());
    db = dbSetup.getWritableDatabase();

    // Делаем запрос
    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + "TABLE_QUESTION", null);

        // Создаем адаптер
        listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(),
                R.layout.list_contents,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"QuestionNumber", "QuestionText"},
                new int[]{R.id.text_one, R.id.text_two},
                0);

        if(!mSearchHead.getText().toString().isEmpty())
            listAdapter.getFilter().filter(mSearchHead.getText().toString());

        // установка слушателя изменения текста
        mSearchHead.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        // Устанавливаем провайдер фильтрации
        listAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            @Override
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {

                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    return db.rawQuery("select * from " + "TABLE_QUESTION", null);
                }
                else {
                    return db.rawQuery("select * from " + "TABLE_QUESTION" + " where " +
                            "QuestionNumber" + "like ?", new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
                }
            }
        });

        // Передаем адаптер нашему ListView
        mListHeads.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // В случае исключения выводим тост сообщение
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Где `"like ?"` студия ругается, и предлагает добавить строку в String. Добавляю, а затем, в приложении пытаюсь произвести поиск но безрезультатно. Список глав отображается как положено, но если я вбиваю что-либо в `EditText` ничего не происходит. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мда, отсутствовал пробел:

```
return db.rawQuery("select * from " + "TABLE_QUESTION" + " where " +
                        "QuestionNumber " + "like ?", new String[]{"%" + constraint.toString() + "%"});
```

После `QuestionNumber` нужно было пробел поставить)